# How to access different columns of a different tables using cursor after a join has been made on a particular column name in the tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

So I am having issues in understanding how can one access different column names using a cursor in which a join operation has been made on three different tables over a single common column.

For example

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR joined_table_cur IS
    SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b.col5, c.col7 ...
    FROM table1 a
    JOIN table2 b ON a.col1 = b.col1 JOIN
    table3 c on b.col1 = c.col1 
;

  joined_table_rec joined_table_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR joined_table_rec IN joined_table_cur
  LOOP    
   -- how to access col7 from table3 ie c in this cursor--
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I am unable to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop through cursor rows in your sample all you should do is to use second type of looping in code below and reference the columns using already declared variable joined_table_rec - for col1 it is **joined_table_rec.col1**, for col2 **joined_table_rec.col2** ... and so on.
If you want to use FOR LOOP then you don't need to declare joined_table_rec variable as the for loop would create the variable itself - just give the name - rec2 in code below.
Below is example for two ways how to loop the cursor:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
          Select 1 "COL_ID", 'Name 1' "COL_NAME", 'Somethong else 1' "COL_ELSE" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 "COL_ID", 'Name 2' "COL_NAME", 'Somethong else 2' "COL_ELSE" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "COL_ID", 'Name 3' "COL_NAME", 'Somethong else 3' "COL_ELSE" From Dual
    );
    rec cur%ROWTYPE;
    m_sql VarChar2(500);
BEGIN

  FOR rec2 IN cur LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec2.COL_ID);
  END LOOP;
  

  OPEN cur;
  LOOP   
        FETCH cur Into rec;
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.COL_NAME);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;
END;

Result: 
anonymous block completed
1
2
3
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
```

More about it [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/implicit-vs-explicit-cursors-in-oracle-plsql).

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer. d r has answered your question and explained the two options how to access your cursor.

I just want to add that you don't need an explicit cursor at all. What I usually do is just this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  (
    SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b.col5, c.col7 ...
    FROM table1 a
    JOIN table2 b ON a.col1 = b.col1
    JOIN table3 c ON b.col1 = c.col1 
  )
  LOOP    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('table1.col1 is ' || rec.col1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('table2.col5 is ' || rec.col5);
    ...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Consider this a comment to dr's answer. I am merely posting this here as an "answer", because without line breaks it would be hard to read as a comment.